# Using cmake for coupling C++ and FORTRAN (mpif90) with iso_c_binding

Tags: c++, cmake, fortran, openmpi, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to write the CMakeLists.txt for coupling a simple FORTRAN program which calls a C++ function using iso_c_binding. When I use gfortran as the FORTRAN compiler, the code works perfectly, but when I switch to openMPI (mpif90) instead of gfortran, I get the error:

```
CMakeFiles/test.exe.dir/main.f90.o: In function `MAIN__':
main.f90:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `mpi_init_'
main.f90:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `mpi_comm_size_'
main.f90:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `mpi_comm_rank_'
main.f90:(.text+0x1c3): undefined reference to `mpi_finalize_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.exe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am attaching the gfortran version (working). In order to switch to the mpif90, I just uncomment the commented lines in the main.f90:

```
program main
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none
!   include 'mpif.h'

   interface
      function func (n,x) bind (C, name="func")
         import
         integer(c_int):: func
         integer(c_int):: n
         real(c_double), dimension(1:n), intent(in):: x
      end function func
   end interface

   integer(c_int):: n
   real(c_double), dimension(:), allocatable:: x
   integer(c_int):: result
!   integer, parameter:: master = 0
!   integer:: numtasks, taskid, ierr, dest
!   integer  status(mpi_status_size)

!   call mpi_init(ierr)
!   call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, numtasks, ierr)
!   call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, taskid, ierr)
!   if (taskid .eq. master) then
      n = 3
      allocate(x(1:n))
      x = (/1., 2., 3./)
      result = func(n,x)
      deallocate(x)
!   end if
!   call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

func.c:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern"C" {
#endif
int func(int& n, double x[]) {
   std::cout << x[0] << "  " << x[1] << "  " << x[2] << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
  }
#endif
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
enable_language(C Fortran)
# -------------------------
# Setting the compilers
# -------------------------
#set (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER /usr/local/openmpi/bin/mpif90)
set (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER /usr/bin/gfortran)
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)
# -------------------------
# Setting the flags
# -------------------------
set_source_files_properties(main.f90 func.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-c -lstdc++")
# -------------------------
# Making the executable
# -------------------------
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test.exe main.f90 func.cpp)
```

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Without changing anything, I can compile and run this code with mpif90 but that's not useful for me since everything is repeated by the number of CPUs used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not linking to MPI anywhere.
Besides, setting the CMAKE_Fortran_compiler by hand is the wrong way to do it as it is not portable at all. Here is a simplified version of what I have in one of my projects.
Note that I am using the FindMPI module that comes with recent versions of cmake. I do not know if cmake version 2.6 has that module but you can easily find it online.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(DYNAMO Fortran C)
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
set(DYNAMO_LINK_LIBRARIES ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
set(DYNAMO_SRCS main.f90)
add_executable(dynamo ${DYNAMO_SRCS})
set_target_properties(dynamo PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set_target_properties(dynamo PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_Fortran_LINK_FLAGS}")
target_link_libraries(dynamo ${DYNAMO_LINK_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS dynamo RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood what you wanted in the first place. What you want is to get rid of MPI, not include it, right. In that case, I think your problem is that you did not do a 'make clean' before recompiling and are just picking up the old objects still referencing mpi.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I have modified the CMakeLists.txt based on yours, but I am now getting the error: `main.f90:5: Error: Can't open included file 'mpif.h' `

Comment: I just saw your comment. Actually, each time I do make clean, and even delete all the files created by cmake. I want to be able to use MPI, so your first answer is in the direction of what I meant.

Comment: OK, that is weird. The file'Mpif.h'. should not be needed because you cemented that line.

Comment: Ok, because you want to use MPI, you should add the following line to your CmakeLists.t×t right after findpackage: include_directories (${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_DIRS}). This should fix your problem.